# Flutter bloc pattern repeat calling function many times

Tags: flutter, provider, bloc

i am trying to use bloc pattern in flutter application i write the code inside body of build function before return Scaffold(); as following

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ProductsController pController = Provider.of<ProductsController>(context);
    pController.addProducts();
    return Scaffold();
}
```

every thing is perfect but the function 
addPrducts() calls too many times it looks the following code repeat it self many times

```
pController.addProducts();
```

here is the structure of ProductsContoller class

```
class ProductsController extends ChangeNotifier {
List<Products> _products=List();
AppDatabase appDB=AppDatabase();
  List<Products> get products=>_products;
addProducts() {
      appDB.getFromTable(AppDatabase.TBL_PRODUCTS).then((rows){
      rows.forEach((row){
        Products product=Products.fromJson(row);
        _products.add(product);


      });
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use  `setState` in your build method?

Comment: no i use bloc to avoid using setState

Answer (score 1):

If your function should only get called once u should try to override the `initState()` Method and call it there. If your class extends a `StatefulWidget` your `build(BuildContext context)` Method possibly gets called multiple times.

```
final ProductsController pController

@override
void initState() {
    pController = Provider.of<ProductsController>(context);
    pController.addProducts();

    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: what cause build method to call multiple times ??

Comment: The framework calls this method in a number of different situations:
After calling initState.
After calling didUpdateWidget.
After receiving a call to setState.
After a dependency of this State object changes (e.g., an InheritedWidget referenced by the previous build changes).
After calling deactivate and then reinserting the State object into the tree at another location. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html

Comment: your way give this exception inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_Provider<ProductsController>) or inheritFromElement() was called
I/flutter ( 6563): before _ReportState.initState() completed.

the _ReprotSate is my Class inhered statefulWidget

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some operation like fetching screen data only once in the stateful widget then you can make use of [`void didChangeDependencies()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html) along with the boolean flag.

> didChangeDependencies() is also called immediately after initState.
>   Also called when a dependency of this State object changes. It is safe to call BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType from this method.

```
final ProductsController pController
var _isLoadingForFirstTime = true;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
}

@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isLoadingForFirstTime) {
       pController = Provider.of<ProductsController>(context);
       pController.addProducts();
    }
    _isLoadingForFirstTime = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(); // You Screen contents here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must define your widget that used your list in other classes (stateful or stateless).

for example, if you use List in ListView, you must create a stateless class for your ListView and watch list in this class.

```
    class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 260,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 4.6,
      ),
      itemCount: context.watch<ProductsController >().productPjo.listProduct.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        return  ItemProduct(context.watch<ProductsController >().productPjo.listProduct[i]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```